# How to capture a sequence of key presses and then fire an event in Qt?

Tags: qt, events

I know how to fire an event on a key press in Qt. But I need to handle a sequence. Fire event only when user presses <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>.

How can I capture this sequence? Just tell me how can I detect which keys were pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `QAction`, add your required key sequence to it with `setShortcut(const QKeySequence& shortcut)`.  Associate the `QAction` by calling `QWidget::addAction(QAction* action)`, and then you can create the appropriate signal/slot connections between the `QAction` and `QWidget`.

Comment: Thanks. Can u explain a little more how the signal in this case be. The event is that user presses the three keys mentioned in the question.

Comment: Depending on the shortcut context (`setShortcutContext(Qt::ShortcutContext context)`), when the key sequence is pressed, the `QAction::triggered(bool checked)` signal is fired - connect to whatever you want.  Read the docs: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html.

Comment: okey = new QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+h"));
    act = new QAction(this);
    act->setShortcut(QKeySequence &okey);   ------ is throwing the error -   error: expected primary-expression before '&' token

Comment: That is not valid C++, nor is it the correct way to call the `setShortcut(..)` method.  `act = new QAction(this); act->setShortcut(QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+h")));`

Comment: Yeah  i realised this jsut after typing n made the change. works smooth thanks

Comment: One last thing. Do i need to set up the shortcut context ? if yes then what exactly it does ?

Comment: How do I add action to the global window instead of a small widget

Comment: The documentation explains context clearly, and the process is exactly the same regardless of `QWidget` type.

Comment: HI I was able to do the operation successfully without context. ON press of CTRL+SHIFT+A  I'm able to exit my application.  I now want to enhance the secret key stroke to CTRL+SHIFT+A+CTRL+SHIFT+C..  However this won't work with the method we discussed now.  I guess set_shortcuts method also won't help. In short I want to have two shortcut sequences. only if both are executed one after the other should my application close.